# MyBatis annotation dynamic query with variable inside select and group

Tags: java, interface, annotations, mybatis

Is it possible for MyBatis select query to read variable value for Select and Group By commands? If it is possible so how should I put the `aggregationKeys` variable inside that places? (Look into the code):

```
@Select({"SELECT #{aggregationKeys}, SUM(value) " +
            "FROM usage_counter WHERE " + /*zrobic mape i pociagnac to tak, ze: (#{zmyslona wartosc} IS NULL OR api_consumer) itd*/
            "(#{apiConsumerIds} IS NULL OR #{apiConsumerIds} like '%,'||api_consumer||',%' ) AND " +
            "(#{serviceIds} IS NULL OR #{serviceIds} like '%,'||service||',%' ) AND " +
            "(#{rateplanIds} IS NULL OR #{rateplanIds} like '%,'||rateplan||',%' ) AND " +
            "(#{dateFrom} IS NULL OR date >= #{dateFrom} ) AND " +
            "(#{dateTo} IS NULL OR date <= #{dateTo} ) AND " +
            "(#{statuses} IS NULL OR #{statuses} like '%,'||counter_status||',%' ) " +
            "GROUP BY ||#{aggregationKeys}||"})
    @Results({
            @Result(property = "date", column = "date"),
            @Result(property = "apiConsumerId", column = "api_consumer"),
            @Result(property = "serviceId", column = "service"),
            @Result(property = "value", column = "value")
    })
    List<AggregatedUsage> getAggregatedUsageCounters(@Param("aggregationKeys") String aggregationKeys, @Param("dateFrom") Date dateFrom, @Param("dateTo") Date dateTo, @Param("apiConsumerIds") String apiConsumerIds, @Param("serviceIds") String serviceIds, @Param("statuses") String statuses);
```

Edit: Or is it possible to do grouping by in Java streams by two or more values (max 4 in this particular case)?

Second Edit: - ok it is possible but I it makes stream very complicated and I think uneffective.

Comment: You have to iterate over the `aggregationKeys` using `forEach`. Just putting `#{aggregationKeys}` will not be sufficient. Even Java Streams you can do aggregation this can be done in the `collect` where there are different `Collectors` defined to achieve this. Otherwise DB group by is fastest